# EZ Publish: Custom datatype not working after upgrading from 4.6 to 4.7

Tags: upgrade, ezpublish

I have a couple of sites running on eZ Publish 4.5. After upgrading to 4.6 everything worked just fine but after upgrading to 4.7 my custom datatype stopped working.

Error: eZDataType::loadAndRegisterType
Datatype not found: 'xxx', searched in these directories: kernel/classes/datatypes

Is this a known issue or has anything changed between 4.6 and 4.7 that I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what just happened but after searching for an answer I reloaded the page and now it works, must been something I did wrong that got cached.